# Optimizing and indexing query with random component

Tags: php, mysql, indexing

I have the following query in the code I've inherited:

```
SELECT  a.row2, a.row3
    FROM  table1 a
    JOIN  table2 b ON a.row1 = b.row1
    WHERE  b.row2 IN (
        SELECT  id
            FROM  table3
            WHERE  id IN ($table3_ids)
                     )
    ORDER BY  RAND();
```

[a.row1 is the primary key for table1]

Several questions:

- Is there a more efficient way to structure this query?
- I already have an index in table1 on (row1, row2, row4); is it redundant to make a separate index for (row1, row2, row3), or should I just replace the former with an index on (row1, row2, row3, row4)?
- From the opposite end, I already have an index in table2 on (row1, row2, row3); since it would seem I need an index in table2 for (row1, row2) to optimize this query, would it be redundant to include an index that simply *excludes* a single element from a different index in the same table?

This is where I'm unclear on how the query engine can know which index is appropriate; when it parses the query, does it first check for matching indices in the table?

- Lastly (and probably most simply answered), I'm adding indices with this syntax:

  ALTER TABLE table_name ADD KEY (row1, row2, row3);

After creating the index, I'm then manually renaming each index descriptively. Is it possible to include the name of the index in the command?

Many thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you mean `column` instead of `row`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT a.row2, a.row3
FROM table1 a JOIN
     table2 b
     ON a.row1 = b.row1
WHERE b.row2 IN (SELECT id FROM table3 WHERE id IN ($table3_ids)) 
ORDER BY RAND();
```

I think the best indexes are:  `table2(row2, row1)` and `table1(row1, row2, row3)`, and `table3(id)`.  You can add `row4` to the `table1` index, but it doesn't make a difference.  Also, it is really odd that you named your columns "row" -- for me it results in cognitive dissonance.

Actually, unless you have a typo in your query, you can leave out `table3` and just do:

```
WHERE b.row2 IN ($table3_ids)
```

Note that `in ($table3_ids)` requires a string substitution.  This cannot be parameterized.  That introduces a danger of SQL injection.

If your result set is more than a few hundred, maybe a few thousand rows, then the `order by` will be significant.  If this is the case, you might want to try a different approach to getting the results you want.

Comment: Many thanks...it was a "brain fart" for me to use "row" instead of "column" in my reduction of the query...my bad, as they say!

Comment: @Tom . . . I couldn't figure out why I had this vague disquiet thinking about your problem, until I realized that the names were the cause ;)

Answer (score 1):

Some additions to Gordon's answer:

The [ALTER TABLE reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table.html) shows an optional `index_name` in the syntax.

`IN ( SELECT ... )` is grossly inefficient; turn it into a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT  a.row2, a.row3
    FROM  table1 a
    JOIN  table2 b ON a.row1 = b.row1
    JOIN  table3 c ON b.row2 = c.id
    WHERE  c.id IN ($table3_ids) )
    ORDER BY  RAND();
```

or...

```
SELECT  a.row2, a.row3
    FROM  table1 a
    JOIN  table2 b ON a.row1 = b.row1
    WHERE b.row2  IN ($table3_ids) )
    ORDER BY  RAND();
```

(A possible reason needing `c`:  You are filtering on missing ids in `c`?)

`ORDER BY RAND()` is costly.  It essentially cannot be optimized unless you also have a `LIMIT`.

Comment: Thanks, @Rick...the second way you proposed is how I read Gordon's suggestion, namely (and rightly using "column" instead of "row"):

SELECT a.column2, a.column3
 FROM  table1 a
 JOIN  table2 b ON a.column1 = b.column1
 WHERE b.column2  IN ($table3_ids)
 ORDER BY  RAND()

The actual query is:

SELECT a.large_image, a.title FROM artwork a JOIN galleries_artwork ga ON a.id = ga.artwork_id WHERE ga.galleries_id IN($question_marks) ORDER BY RAND()